# Color scale - close but not close enough

Tags: python, numpy, plot, colormap

I'm trying to produce a plot which uses the same colorscale as the Met Office, so I can easily compare my plots to theirs. An example of theirs is at [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRjiV.gif)

My current closest effort is here:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAy1M.png)

I appreciate my code is messy - I couldn't find a way to set a color for values above a certain threshold (otherwise it goes white),hence the loop.

I would upload the NetCDF File but I haven't got a high enough rep to do this.

Many, many thanks in advance for any help.

My code for plotting is shown below;

```
from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile                     
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap                     
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt                      
import numpy as np


myfile = NetCDFFile('ERA_Dec_89-94.nc', 'r')   
Lat = NetCDFFile('/home/james/Documents/Lat_Lon_NC_Files/latitudes_d02.nc','r')
Long = NetCDFFile('/home/james/Documents/Lat_Lon_NC_Files/longitudes_d02.nc','r')


XLAT = Lat.variables['XLAT'][:]     
XLONG = Long.variables['XLONG'][:]      
ERA_Data = myfile.variables['Monthlyrain'][:]

plot = np.zeros([1000,1730])

plot[:,:] = np.average(ERA_Data[:,:,:],axis=0)

m = Basemap(projection='merc',resolution='f',llcrnrlat=49,llcrnrlon=-11,urcrnrlat=61,urcrnrlon=3)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 91., 5.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=11)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 5.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=11)
m.drawcoastlines()


X, Y = m(XLONG, XLAT)

for i in range(0,1729):
    for j in range(0,999):
         if plot[j,i] >250:
             plot[j,i] = 250.001
         if plot[j,i] < 40:
             plot[j,i] = 40

scale = [40,40.001,60,80,100,125,150,200,250, 250.001]
cs = m.contourf(X,Y,plot,scale, cmap='PuOr')
cbar = m.colorbar(cs, ticks=  [40.0005,50,70,90,112.5,137.5,175,225,250.0005])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['<40','40-60', '60-80', '80-100', '100-125', '125-150', '150-200', '200-250', '>250'])

plt.title('Some Title')
cbar.set_label('Monthly average rainfall (mm)')

print "Finished"

plt.show()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want the colors to match more closely? Do you want to restrict plotting to the land mass? Something else, entirely? The more specific your questions the higher the chance someone has a good answer...

Comment: Sorry - the two components I needed help were with the colors to match more closely (I think xnx answered so I'll give this a go), and also how to assign a color to any value that exceeds a threshold (eradicating the need for the loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part (getting the colors right) [was already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270110/3005167). In order to restrict the values to a certain range you have several options.

- Use `cmap.set_over` and `cmap.set_under` to set out-of-bounds colors, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386204/3005167)
- use [`np.clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) instead of the loop to restrict the values to a certian range:

  `plot = np.clip(plot, 40, 250)`

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is simply the colormap, you can pick the RGB components of the colors off your screen and turn them into a [`ListedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap), mapped to the boundaries of the rainfall in the chart you give as an example. For example,

```
bounds = [0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 1000]
rgblist = [(51,0,0), (102,51,0), (153,102,51), (204,153,102), (255, 255, 255),
           (204,204,255), (153,153,255), (51,102,255), (0,0,153)]
clist = [[c/255 for  c in rgb] for rgb in rgblist]

from matplotlib import colors
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(clist)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

ax.imshow(arr, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'll give this a go!

Comment: Question - where can I find the numbers for each colour? How do I know what values to use for RGBlist? Thanks

Comment: There are lots of tools for doing this. eg on a Mac, in Applications/Utilities/Digital Color Meter is an application for determining the RGB components of the pixel under the cursor.

Comment: Unfortunately It produces this kind of plot. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4A445014A6259A95!153585&authkey=!ABQ6TMN4lDKrtTc&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: 'plot = np.clip(plot,40,250)
    bounds = [0, 40, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300]
    rgblist = [(51,25,0), (102,51,0), (153,76,0), (239,159,80), (255, 255, 255),
           (153,204,255), (51,153,255), (0,102,204), (2,2,128)]

clist = [[c/255 for  c in rgb] for rgb in rgblist]
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(clist)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
cs = m.contourf(X,Y,plot,bounds, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = m.colorbar(cs, ticks=[20,50,70,90,112.5,137.5,175,225,275])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['<40','40-60', '60-80', '80-100', '100-125', '125-150', '150-200', '200-250', '>250'])'

Comment: solved - issue was 255 needed to be 255. to avoid division errors in Python 2.x

Comment: Sorry about that - I had my Python 3 hat on. Glad it was helpful.