# Python histogram with pre-set size of bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

How would I go by if I wanted to plot a histogram when I already have the bins and their size ?

If I use :

```
plt.hist(x, bins)
```

it considers x as a list of results and not the already defined value of the corresponding bin.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can simply create a bar chart with [`plt.bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270110/3005167):

```
plt.bar(bins[:, 0], x, bins[:, 1] - bins[:, 0])
```

I simply assumed `bins` is an array of shape `(n, 2)`, where `n`is the number of bins. The first column is the lowest value covered by the bin and the second column is the upper value covered by the bin.